# How does an aggregate root ensure the integrity of the aggregate if it is 'IN' the aggregate?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

So I'm still trying to reach that "aha!" moment with aggregates and aggregate roots (what's new, right?) and I see that Martin Fowler said the following:

> *An aggregate will have one of its component objects be the aggregate root. Any references from outside the aggregate should only go to the
>   aggregate root. The root can thus ensure the integrity of the
>   aggregate as a whole.*

So I'm reading this as the aggregate is the parent object and one of the objects IN the aggregate is selected as the aggregate root. Anything outside of this aggregate can only hold a reference to the root. This is confusing to me. If the root is *part* of the aggregate, how can it ensure anything?

It's my understanding that the entire purpose of the aggregate is to a) serve as a logical grouping of domain objects (value objects and other aggregates) and b) act as a transactional boundary from which all interaction with the aggregates must occur, and that repos only deal with aggregates. But say I have an aggregate like this:

```
public class UserInventory
{
        private List<InventoryItem> _inventoryItems;

        // the aggregate root
        public User User { get; }       

        public ReadOnlyCollection<InventoryItem> Inventory => _inventoryItems;

        public UserInventory(User root, IEnumerable<InventoryItem> inventory)
        {
            User = root;
            _inventoryItems = inventory;
        }

        public void UpdateItemDescription(Guid itemId, ItemDescription newDescription)
        {
            _inventoryItems.Single(i => i.Id == itemId).Description = newDescription;
            DomainEvents.Notify(new InventoryItemUpdated(User));
        }
}
```

Now my app layer wants to change the description on a particular inventory item, so, since it's not supposed to talk directly to the inventory items, I expose `UpdateItemDescription(Guid, ItemDescription)` to control this process as this would be the opportunity for the aggregate to enforce any invariants (which I left out for clarity)

I feel like this is a decent example of an aggregate, but I don't understand how having an aggregate root does anything for "ensuring integrity" here. I've looked at the C# DDD sample application, but I couldn't find any obvious answers to my question, but feel free to reference it in your answers.

Could anyone clarify? Am I missing something or misunderstanding something?

Comment: While DDD started like a mix of design and coding, these days it's a app design methodology (identifying the domain model), but it kept the old names like value _object_ or aggregate root. Thing is, many devs are using a functional approach these days and they don't have many objects, but they are doing DDD and they _implement_ the aggregate root as a _function_. You can say that the AR is the facade of the aggregate in charge of enforcing the aggregate consistency rules, regardless of how it's implemented.

Answer (score 8):

It has to do with [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) (a fundamental OOP principle). Let's take a moment and look at this public contract:

```
public class UserInventory
{
        public User User { get; }       
        public ReadOnlyCollection<InventoryItem> Inventory => _inventoryItems;
}
```

What you've done here is to introduce two weaknesses. The first one is to expose one aggregate root from another one. This means that someone could do:

```
inventory.User.FirstName = "Arne";
_inventoryRepository.Update(inventory);
```

That's an violation of [Law Of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Whould that code work? Probably not as the responsibility of the inventory repository is to persist the inventory object. Everything else would lead to a big ball of mud in the data layer (i.e. every repository need to be able to invoke all other repositories etc) and in the business layer (when is a change like that allowed/valid?)

So start by referencing ids of other root aggregates:

```
public class UserInventory
{
        public int UserId { get; }       
        public ReadOnlyCollection<InventoryItem> Inventory => _inventoryItems;
}
```

The next problem is that you expose the `InventoryItem` list. And that's what the DDD book is talking about. The `Inventory` class is not in control over it's aggregates. Let's say that you have a `TotalValue` property in your `Inventory`:

```
public class UserInventory
{
        public int UserId { get; }       
        public ReadOnlyCollection<InventoryItem> Inventory => _inventoryItems;
        public decimal TotalValue {get; set; }
}
```

What happens if someone adjusts the price directly on an inventory item?

```
inventory.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name = XX).Value = 456.32;
```

Would the total reflect the correct value? No. Because you have not protected the aggregates.

A proper design is simply not to expose the items:

```
public class UserInventory
{
        private List<InventoryItem> _inventoryItems;

        public UserInventory(User root, IEnumerable<InventoryItem> inventory)
        {
            User = root;
            _inventoryItems = inventory;
        }

        public int UserId { get; }       

        public void UpdateItemDescription(Guid itemId, ItemDescription newDescription)
        {
            _inventoryItems.Single(i => i.Id == itemId).Description = newDescription;
            DomainEvents.Notify(new InventoryItemUpdated(User));
        }
}
```

Now you ask. *If I'm going to do bloody proper encapsulation everywhere, how the freck can I display stuff to the user?*

Separate the write model form the read model. When you query stuff from your repository with the purpose of DISPLAYING information you can return DTOs instead. They do not contain any methods and just represent state.

When it's time do do some work the application service can use the repository to fetch the real object, do operations on it and later persist it.

> So in this example, the UserInventory is a domain object selected as the root of the UserInventory-User-Inventory aggregate? And all domain objects that are members of the aggregate that are not roots are held within the root as private members to which access is exposed through explicit behaviors on the root? Can you recommend any good patterns or examples of how to get state out of the roots?

When moving toward correctly designed DDD, CQRS is a very good fit. Because in CQRS, you clearly distinguish between what's read and what's written. Anything you use for reading (i.e., displaying information for the user) is not reused in the write site. What drives the write side is rather task-based actions. i.e. instead of saying *update fields A, B, and C to these values*, the commands focus more on business actions *Complete the order using information A and B*. The distinction is quite important as the commands do not affect the underlying domain model structure at all. What I mean is that your domain is not exposed anywhere in the write model. All changes are driven through the commands.

It also means that the read side can contain specialized objects which fulfill specific uses cases. I personally create objects which solves specific needs in the UI. My order entity might be represented by `OrderListDTO` which a minimal set of properties per row to be able to display an overview while "OrderDetailsDTO" represents specifics for an order.

If you are not ready for that change (protect your domain with CQRS) you can specialize your application by creating specialized application services for the read and write models.

The important transition is to recognize that there is not a single representation of an Order, but different ones depending on how the order is consumed in the top layer.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this applies _only_ with a full OOP implementation. If you go functional, the implementation will be different but the aggregate and its root will still be the same. It's important to distinguish between the abstraction (the DDD concept of aggregate together with entities, VO, AR etc) and its implementation which is the actual code.

Comment: I see. So in this example, the UserInventory is a domain object selected as the root of the UserInventory-User-Inventory aggregate? And all domain objects that are members of the aggregate that are not roots are held within the root as private members to which access is exposed through explicit behaviors on the root? Can you recommend any good patterns or examples of how to get state out of the roots?

Comment: Also +1 for "Now you ask. If I'm going to do bloody proper encapsulation everywhere, how the freck can I display stuff to the user?" because that is EXACTLY what I was thinking lol

Comment: Read my update. How you understand a bit of my ramblings :)

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Need any more info?

Comment: I think I got what I needed. Not quite ready to be dabbling in CQRS, but I have a pretty decent pattern that I'm working with now that jives well with the repo pattern so I think I'm nice and comfy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> An aggregate will have one of its component objects be the aggregate root. Any references from outside the aggregate should only go to the aggregate root. The root can thus ensure the integrity of the aggregate as a whole.
>
> So I'm reading this as the aggregate is the parent object

That's not quite right.  The "aggregate", as described by Evans, is not an object.  It's more accurate to think of it as a subset of the domain, composed of some state, and all of the business rules that interact with that state.

The key idea being the *boundary* -- if you need to change data inside the aggregate, then everything you need to insure the integrity of the change is also within the boundary.  Likewise, if you need to change data outside the aggregate, then you don't need any of the state within the aggregate.

As jgauffin said, "encapsulation".

> If the root is part of the aggregate, how can it ensure anything?

Because "tell, don't ask"

The aggregate root is the only entity within the aggregate that is exposed.  It is literally the root of the object graph within the aggregate; every piece of state in the aggregate can be reached by traversing to it from the aggregate root.

Every mutation of data within the aggregate requires executing a command on the aggregate root.  If the command would produce an invalid state, then the root is responsible for rejecting the command.  So the rules can be coded into the root object itself, or they can be delegated to other objects within the same aggregate.

The usual style is that entities within the aggregate are responsible for their own state, and the parent entities are responsible for enforcing coordination among children.  But that's just implementation detail -- it's not at all unusual for an aggregate to contain only a single root entity that is responsible for everything.

In short, when you load "the aggregate", you are loading the entire object graph -- not just the root.  The aggregate is loaded in a valid state -- all rules are satisfied.  The only way that you can change the state of the aggregate is by running a command exposed by the root entity; the root entity is responsible for rejecting any command that would violate the integrity rules.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that an aggregate is not an object but subset of the domain. It seems few developers understand that.

Comment: Yeah, that's a very important point and I think this is the first time I've seen anyone point that out. The wording is misleading. So just so we're clear, the aggregate isn't something I can point to in the solution? It's something I have to describe/document like "This account object is the aggregate root of the account-user-merchant-customer aggregate." for example?